# How to calculate the variance/ standard deviation of a sum of ratios (X1+X2+X3+...)/Y?

Tags: linear-algebra, random-variables, variance, covariance, simulation

I calculated the correlation matrixes between each variable and i found that some are correlated some are not ?
what should i do to find out the variance of the sum of all random variables divided by a random variable (costs divided by cycle time which is also a random variable)

[Here is the correlation matrix i generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL9XP.png)
thank you very much

Comment: Edit: i found this but i don't know if it is related or solves my problem ?http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/files/ratio.pdf

Comment: I'm guessing that the sum on top goes from $1$ to $Y$ and that $Y$ is an integer. In that case I would suggest you compute the conditional variance given $Y$ and then apply the usual formulas.

Comment: @P.Quinton, thank you for your answer, but why conditional variance ? (the goal is to find the mean cost per time unit, so i am divding the total cost per time and all is random variables as they depend on simulation results using as entry random variables )

Comment: If you have the conditional variance then you can find the variance using this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance#Explanation,_relation_to_least-squares so all you have to know is $\mathrm{Var}[U|Y]$ and $\mathbb E[U|Y]$ where $U$ is your thing.